# There's no error but data is not inserted to sql server table using ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

The insert query is not giving any error but the data is not getting inserted into the DB. When I check the database in sql server, there seems to be no data insertion. I'm not sure which part of the code has an error.

The following code:

````
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace PayrollSystem05
{
    public partial class employee : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
      protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


protected void btnAdd_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-M0G68DT\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=PRS;Integrated Security=True");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO [payslip].[employee]
           ([emp_id]
           ,[emp_name]
           ,[emp_ic]
           ,[emp_address]
           ,[emp_mobile]
           ,[emp_email]
           ,[emp_startdate])
     VALUES
           ('"+ txtID.Text +"', '"+ txtName.Text +"', '"+ txtIC.Text +"', '"+ txtAdd.Text + "', '"+ txtMob.Text +"', '"+ txtEmail.Text +"', '" + txtStart.Text + "')", con);
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Employee added successfully.')</script>");
        }
    }
}```
````

Comment: Can you please check where your database is located whether it is in SQL Server orSQL Server Express?

Comment: It's in SQL Server, just figured out there's errors in the SQL queries.

Comment: use store procedure instead of inline which help to debug this easily

Answer (score 1):

You can take the code below it's the same that your code, i make just some changes to be more clear and readable.

```
var connectionString = @"Data Source=DESKTOP-M0G68DT\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=PRS;Integrated Security=True";
var queryString = @"INSERT INTO [payslip].[employee]
           (
              [emp_id]
             ,[emp_name]
             ,[emp_ic]
             ,[emp_address]
             ,[emp_mobile]
             ,[emp_email]
             ,[emp_startdate]
            )
          VALUES
            (
              @emp_id
             ,@emp_name
             ,@emp_ic
             ,@emp_address
             ,@emp_mobile
             ,@emp_email
             ,@emp_startdate
            )";

        using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand command = sqlConnection.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = queryString;
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emp_id", txtID.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emp_name", txtName.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emp_ic", txtIC.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emp_address", txtAdd.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emp_mobile", txtMob.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emp_email", txtEmail.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emp_startdate", txtStart.Text);

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            } 
        }
        Response.Write("<script>alert('Employee added successfully.')</script>");
```